# What effect does HttpResponse#close( ) have on BasicHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-commons-httpclient

I read on the Apache HttpClients tutorial that `HttpResponse#close()` shuts down and discards the connection. My question is when we use a `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager` which only manages a single connection, I call `HttpResponse#close()` will I not be able to reuse the same HttpClient because the connection has been shut down and discarded?

Also, when I do not set a Connection Manager explicitly. Which connection manager is used by the client.

My HttpClients version is 4.5.X.

Comment: You could maybe link to the tutorial you are reading, and/or quote the specific lines that you are refering to. It may be valuable to evaluate to what extent the tutorial uses the right specific terminology and/or to what extent you/we understand it right.

Answer (score 0):

When a client calls a remote server, a connection is established on both parties this is called a [socket connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket). The socket [remains active](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20939193/2704032) until either parties  `close` it.

To answer your question, you can still use the same `HttpClient`, but you will create a new connection to make another request